# How to add OnPointerDown Listener to Slider Handle in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

how do I add a listener on Unity GUI Slider to listen to the mouse down event on the slider handle?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unity UI [Slider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Slider.html) already listens to *OnPointerDown* as you can see it in the docs.

If you want to change the way it behaves or add some custom behaviour to this method you can do it different ways:

**1-** Add an [EventTrigger](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-EventTrigger.html) to your object and selecting the *OnPointerDown* event as follow:

[image: EventTrigger component added to a GameObject]

**2-** Declaring a new class that inherits from **Slider** class and overriding the `OnPointerDown()` method  like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class CustomSlider: Slider
{
    public override void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        base.OnPointerDown(eventData);

        // Your code here
    }
}
```

Note the second method will detect pointer down event on all the slider graphics while you can attach the **EventTrigger** component to the handle alone to detect pointer down event on this graphic element only.

*Hope this helps,*

Comment: To anyone who downvoted please explain why: I'd be more than happy to improve my answer subsequently :)

Comment: How do I use method #2? I created the script subclassing the Slider, but how do I add this custom slider to a Canvas object like I would do with a regular slider?

Comment: @SirPaulMuaddib You simply have to go on your GameObject, click _Add component_ and search for _CustomSlider_ component. Also make sure the .cs file name matches the class name: otherwise Unity won't recognize it as a component.

Comment: Actually works perfectly, didn´t know you can also add event trigger as component, awesome.